# Mysql max function return one null row if nothing found. However, I need it dose not return any row in this case

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this: "**`SELECT MAX(field1), field2, 'constant' AS field3 FROM table`**".
I want that Mysql dose not return any row when field1 and field2 are null. However, when I use MAX function, Mysql return following result:

```
NULL, NULL, 'constant'
```

How can I write a query that dose not return anything in this case?

Comment: MySQL always has to return something.  If the max is `NULL`, what do you want to see?

Comment: Try using group by + having clause since you are using an aggregate function in select clause.

Comment: @Vibhas Do you think is there any other way without using group by?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I need to return no row instead of Null, Null, 'constant'.

Comment: You can use subqueries queries which may cause performance issue.

Comment: @Vibhas Thanks, is there any way to use IF statement?

Comment: I don't think IF condition will be useful here as it works at column level.But you want result to filtered which is an row level operation.

Comment: @Vibhas, check my answer, hope it helps. If solves your your problem, do accept and vote up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove results if aggregate function returns null Via Having clause.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(field1),
    field2,
    'constant' AS field3 
FROM table
HAVING MAX(field1) IS NOT NULL;
```